# Flexbox responsiveness 3 columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made a page to practice using flexbox. It has 1 container in red with 3 flex items. When I minimize the screen the items drop below each other but do not use up the full width of container.

How can I achieve this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.one,
.two-a,
.two-b,
.three {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: arial;
}

h2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- <h2>Flexbox</h2> -->

  <div class="one col">
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget dui ut justo auctor semper a ullamcorper justo. Morbi placerat tortor tortor, ac dignissim leo semper ac. Donec non metus sit amet neque eleifend rhoncus vitae id dolor. Etiam vestibulum
      lobortis sem semper laoreet. Vestibulum egestas elit sed lacus egestas, placerat congue erat faucibus. Nunc ac dui auctor, fermentum turpis ac, mattis magna. Nulla pellentesque, ligula vel faucibus imperdiet, arcu ligula ornare quam, et blandit
      risus sem sit amet neque. Curabitur commodo dui et metus suscipit, ut dignissim risus hendrerit. Quisque at odio nec risus condimentum ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet felis sit amet neque aliquet auctor sed nec metus. Sed gravida mattis sem, nec finibus
      diam suscipit sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two col">
    <div class="two-a">
      <h3>Step 2a</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget dui ut justo auctor semper a ullamcorper justo. Morbi placerat tortor tortor, ac dignissim leo semper ac. Donec non metus sit amet neque eleifend rhoncus vitae id dolor. Etiam
        vestibulum lobortis sem semper laoreet. Vestibulum egestas elit sed lacus egestas, placerat congue erat faucibus. Nunc ac dui auctor, fermentum turpis ac, mattis magna. Nulla pellentesque, ligula vel faucibus imperdiet, arcu ligula ornare quam,
        et blandit risus sem sit amet neque. Curabitur commodo dui et metus suscipit, ut dignissim risus hendrerit. Quisque at odio nec risus condimentum ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet felis sit amet neque aliquet auctor sed nec metus. Sed gravida mattis
        sem, nec finibus diam suscipit sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two-b">
      <h3>Step 2b</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget dui ut justo auctor semper a ullamcorper justo. Morbi placerat tortor tortor, ac dignissim leo semper ac. Donec non metus sit amet neque eleifend rhoncus vitae id dolor. Etiam
        vestibulum lobortis sem semper laoreet. Vestibulum egestas elit sed lacus egestas, placerat congue erat faucibus. Nunc ac dui auctor, fermentum turpis ac, mattis magna. Nulla pellentesque, ligula vel faucibus imperdiet, arcu ligula ornare quam,
        et blandit risus sem sit amet neque. Curabitur commodo dui et metus suscipit, ut dignissim risus hendrerit. Quisque at odio nec risus condimentum ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet felis sit amet neque aliquet auctor sed nec metus. Sed gravida mattis
        sem, nec finibus diam suscipit sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three col">
    <h3>Step 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget dui ut justo auctor semper a ullamcorper justo. Morbi placerat tortor tortor, ac dignissim leo semper ac. Donec non metus sit amet neque eleifend rhoncus vitae id dolor. Etiam vestibulum
      lobortis sem semper laoreet. Vestibulum egestas elit sed lacus egestas, placerat congue erat faucibus. Nunc ac dui auctor, fermentum turpis ac, mattis magna. Nulla pellentesque, ligula vel faucibus imperdiet, arcu ligula ornare quam, et blandit
      risus sem sit amet neque. Curabitur commodo dui et metus suscipit, ut dignissim risus hendrerit. Quisque at odio nec risus condimentum ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet felis sit amet neque aliquet auctor sed nec metus. Sed gravida mattis sem, nec finibus
      diam suscipit sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget dui ut justo auctor semper a ullamcorper justo. Morbi placerat tortor tortor, ac dignissim leo semper ac. Donec non metus sit amet neque eleifend rhoncus vitae id dolor. Etiam vestibulum
      lobortis sem semper laoreet. Vestibulum egestas elit sed lacus egestas, placerat congue erat faucibus. Nunc ac dui auctor, fermentum turpis ac, mattis magna. Nulla pellentesque, ligula vel faucibus imperdiet, arcu ligula ornare quam, et blandit
      risus sem sit amet neque. Curabitur commodo dui et metus suscipit, ut dignissim risus hendrerit. Quisque at odio nec risus condimentum ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet felis sit amet neque aliquet auctor sed nec metus. Sed gravida mattis sem, nec finibus
      diam suscipit sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/cian-w/pen/EQZmRz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rule limiting the width of flex items:

```
.col {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Therefore, the items cannot fill the full width of the container because they cannot expand beyond 400px. Try this instead:

```
.col {
    flex: 1 0 400px;
}
```

This shorthand declaration breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: 400px`

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqpWrb)